# What does assumption and inconsistency mean in Bias-Variance dilemma?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, training-data, variance

I'm reading about machine learning and trying to understand what bias and variance mean. I've read these articles ([1](https://ml.berkeley.edu/blog/2017/07/13/tutorial-4/), [2](https://elitedatascience.com/bias-variance-tradeoff), [3](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-to-the-bias-variance-trade-off-in-machine-learning/) ), but still have a few questions:

1. Bias:

   > model is biased in that it assumes that the data will behave in a
   >   certain fashion (linear, quadratic, etc.) even though that assumption
   >   may not be true

   What does it mean "assume"? We select the model we want to use. If we select a linear model then it will try to fit the best line it can do.
2. Variance:

   > variance measures how inconsistent are the predictions from one
   >   another over different training sets

   Why it should be consistent if we use different training set? If we use data of cats it will give one predictions. If we use data of dogs, it will give us different predictions. Or do they mean that when we add more observations to our training set the predictions should improve and not that model now gives us different prediction than from before?

Comment: 1 - *Assume* is just the way they've explained the function approximation by the model. Eg., say the actual underlying function of the data set is `y=2x + 10`, and our model approximated something like `y=3x + 9` when we selected a linear model for this task. Another linear model will approximate `y=2.5x + 10`. *Assume* is a metaphor that they've used to denote function approximation done by the linear model - not the assumptions we did to select a linear model for this task.

Comment: 2 - I'm not clear about: `variance measures how inconsistent are the predictions from one another over different training sets`. Here's my view on variance: It occurs when you try to overfit the model to the training set. Assume we have a nonlinear 2D data set from the underlying distribution `y=x^3` with some outliers around `(0, 50)` and nothing else around `(0, 0)`. We train our model until our model approximates a function that fits exactly to the training set (a curve that goes through all the points there). But we didn't know the underlying function of our data is just a `y=x^3` function

Comment: Now, when we evaluate the model by presenting some testing data that belong to a `y = x^3` distribution, the model will predict values around 50 for `x` values around 0; because the model fails to generalize by thinking that above outlier points represent the actual behavior of the underlying data when `x` is around 0. When this happened across several regions, the model would predict results (on the tets data) that never resemble the underlying distribution while having achieved almost perfect performance on the training data.

Comment: Apart from this, I think this question better suits for crossvalidated.

Comment: @akilat90, but even wikipedia says `Bias is an error from erroneous assumptions in the learning algorithm.`. What are the assumptions in this case then?

Comment: In the context of this question- since we had a problem about the word *assumption* - I'd paraphrase that to `Bias is an error from erroneous assumptions in **selecting** the learning algorithm.`. Example: We have a 2D data set that clearly resembles a `y=x^2` curve but we select a linear model of signature `y=ax +b` to train a regression model. Now the model performs poorly during both training and testing phases because we made an *error* in assuming that the underlying data is linear. Long story short: we tried to approximate a complex curve to a simple curve assuming the problem is simple!

Comment: In (1): `model is biased in that it assumes that the data will behave in a certain fashion (linear, quadratic, etc.) even though that assumption may not be true` <- This just paraphrases what I mentioned in my previous comment. My first comment was with regards to `What does it mean "assume"? We select the model we want to use. If we select a linear model then it will try to fit the best line it can do.`. Hope it won't confuse you.

Comment: It seems like I made an *assumption* that you made an *assumption* about the quote regarding bias :D I had an understanding that by `...If we select a linear model then it will try to fit the best line it can do.` you meant about model trying to *assume* (approximate underlying distribution - model fitting) data distribution - seems it isn't the case. So my first comment shouldn't have `Assume is just the way **they've** explained .. `. They just say: `Do not try to approximate a complex curve to a simple curve assuming the problem is simple!` Sorry I think I've confused you,too late to edit:(

Comment: so, Bias is when we assume certain things about the training data (it's shape for example) and we choose a model accordingly. But, then we get predictions far away from the exptected values and we realise that we did a mistake in certain assumptions of our training data? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When we choose a simple model to train our training data on, the data should meet certain criterias (like zero mean error if we choose linear regression model). If the data doesn't meet those criterias the predictions will be poor since a simple model is designed to learn certain type of data. So, the data is biased to the model. But, if we use a model that can handle different shapes of data, it’s not biased, it doesn’t depend on the data and can learn different shapes of data, then we say it’s low bias model, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172525/discussion-between-akilat90-and-theateist).